# Understanding onion architecture

Tags: automapper, onion-architecture

[Onion Architecture Mockups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fjtH.png)

Above are two images that depict my understanding of Onion Architecture.
They are slightly different from the drawings found online, because they address an agenda that I cannot find an answer to.

Infrastructure, as far as I can tell, are things like persistence, logging, etc. I have written examples of them in italics. However, a lot of the time, infrastructure components, as well as UI, tend to need to communicate with one another. The UI might want to audit or log something, the persistence project may need to log something. Logging being one of the harder to fit items in onion architecture, my understanding is that a lot of people have different opinions on where you should and shouldn't log.

In my first drawing, I have put an Infrastructure Interfaces layer in the diagram to allow cross communication without any one component knowing the implementation of another component. This is something that I have seen in a few examples.

The second drawing is my preference, it uses a mediator to cross communicate between infrastructure, UI, and its basically a way to allow the core services to communicate with infrastructure indirectly (assume Service Interfaces is called Core Services on the right diagram). The logger would subscribe itself to certain events, as would the database etc.

The first diagram allows only pocos and interfaces in all layers except the outer layer (excluding the dependency resolver). The second allows domain and business logic in the core service layer and allow the infrastructure layers to do their jobs in isolation.

I justified the infrastructure components by ensuring that they had an output of some sort. Auditing and Logging would usually use a db of some sort, cache would usually store in memory and db should probably have been called persistence. However, there is a library called AutoMapper. I have seen it wrapped in some instances, so that its interface can go in the Core to be used in pretty much any infrastructure, but it seems like over abstraction to me. Automapper is kind of like the Events object in that all infrastructures use it to translate between itself and the domain, but I'm not sure if it fits in that layer since it is not a service.

**Question: Which of the two is closest to the definition of onion architecture and where would you fit in a tool like auto mapper, and do you think trying to wrap something like that is over abstraction?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Auto Mapper and the Onion Architecture. We configured AutoMapper in the MVC Global.asax file, that typically calls a Config Method in the AutoMapperConfig Class in the App Start directory.

Regarding your graphics, it appears one of them has a separate layer for the Mediator and Observer Patters. They're not necessarily needed but it entirely depends on your approach. Just as you can use Model-View-Controller Pattern in the Onion Architecture or Model-View-Presenter or Model-View-ViewModel. They're just coupling separate Patterns to incorporate some added benefit.

Here's where I first came across [the Onion Architecture Jeffery Palermo](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/). If you're wanting to a see a more pure graphical representation.

Comment: You're right, in my second diagram, I am embedding a design pattern into my architecture diagram. Events are just another infrastructural concern. I guess I was asking two questions here: 

1) how do I keep infrastructural code separate yet ensure things like auditing when operating on the db without making it a business concern.

I think that basically, this can be achieved using composition. Or better yet, use aspect oriented patterns and allow technical requirements to be defined in one place: The composition root.

2) where does a tool like automapper fit?